# Books on real-world statistical blunders

Tags: references

What are some good books or resources that give real-world examples of statistical blunders? Wikipedia calls them [Misuse of Statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misuse_of_statistics).

I would like to read about examples such as [this](http://www.quackwatch.org/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/emf.html), where a study that claimed higher incidence of leukemia in children living in close proximity to high-power lines was shown to have [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias).

Comment: Actually the Wiki article provides quite extensive bibliography: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misuse_of_statistics#Bibliography